# small problem using PHP mail function with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, email, function

I'm getting the following error when submitting an email contact form using PHP mail function and jQuery:

SMTP server response: 554 The message was rejected because it contains prohibited virus or spam content in mail.php on line 26

Here is the code I'm using for the PHP:

```
   $mailTo = "info@***.com";
   $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
   $subject = "RFP Inquiry";
   $message = $_POST['message'];


   mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, "From: ".$mailFrom);
```

Here is the code I'm using for the jQuery AJAX call:

```
    //var name = $("#contactname").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#subject").val();
//var age = $("#message").val();
   var datastr ='email=' + email + 'message=' + message;


  $('#submit').click(function(){

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mail.php",
data: datastr,
cache: false,
 error: function () {

    alert('did not go thru');
   },
success: function(html){
//$("#response").fadeIn("slow");
$("#tab1").html(html);
//setTimeout('$("#response").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
alert('mail sent');
}
});


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an ampersand in your `datastr`:

```
var datastr ='email=' + email + 'message=' + message;
```

should be

```
var datastr ='email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
```

**UPDATE**

The SMTP error is coming from the SMTP server, so you should speak to whoever runs that and find out what criteria they have set in order to detect Spam.

My *guess* is that an email with no body constitutes Spam by their definition. The error with `datastr` above would result in a NULL body. Also, if you're doing testing without putting any prose in the `message` text box, that would also result in a zero-length body.

Note... I'm speculating as to why your messages are being considered Spam... talk to the SMTP server owner to find out more.

Comment: NB: That might not be the *whole* solution... but it's a start

Comment: yeah, I too had problems in the past of messages being blocked by the server because of an empty body..

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use:

```
data: ({email : $("#email").val(), message: $("#message").val()}),
```

Maybe the problem occurs in your mail function.
It would be more clear if you post your mail function's code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the entire mail function code. the first section is commented out b/c i thought something was wrong with it.

```
    <?php
/*
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = "info@***.com";
    $email_from2 = $visitor_email;
    $email_subject = "Inquiry";
    $email_body = "here is the body of the message".


    $to = "info@***.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from";
    //$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email";
    //Send email!
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
*/

$mailTo = "info@***.com";
$mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "Inquiry";
$message = $_POST['message'];


mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, "From: ".$mailFrom);
?>
```